# Roku: How to detect a slow device from a fast one

Tags: memory, roku

I have a channel that I want stop animations from happening if running on a slower device like Roku Express and keep them on a faster device like Roku Premiere. Except I'm not sure what's the best way to go about it.

I wanted to filter by the amount of available ram, but I couldn't find an api that gives me available ram for the system that I could run in my code.

I could filter by model name, but I would then need to keep an update list of model names, which I prefer not to do.

Any help/insight appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re graphic capabilities, try [roDeviceInfo.getGraphicsPlatform()](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifDeviceInfo#ifDeviceInfo-GetGraphicsPlatform()asString) - if it returns `opengl`, that high performing engine that can do arbitrary rotations vs `directfb` being limited.

Re CPU, you can run a mini benchmark on start of your program, something like

```
ti = createObject("roTimeSpan"): s=""
for i = 1 to 1000: s = s + right((i^3).toStr(),2): end for
time = ti.totalMilliSeconds()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Animation](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Animation).optional=true?

It won't stop them from happening on Roku Express (since it is a [Littlefield](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/The+Roku+Channel+Developer+Program#TheRokuChannelDeveloperProgram-SupportedModels)) but it will "skip animations on lower performing Roku devices (Paolo, Giga, Jackson, Tyler, and Sugarland)".

Animation also contains an undocumented field called "willBeSkipped" which will be true on slower devices when "optional" is set to true.

Comment: I didn't know about this field. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with the animations. Unfortunately, You must filter by model name. I didn't find another way.
You can store the list of devices in database so it would be easier for You to maintain.

Comment: i wouldn't recommend it, since usually there are better ways - and model# can be misleading. For example, model 2400 performs better than 2450 and resemblance in numbering notwithstanding, there are different platforms

Comment: Yeah, I thought that '' filter by device'' solution is not the best one but at the time I couldn't find the better one. Thanks for the heads up! Your answer should be accepted as the best one.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the optional field on the animation node to true. This is supposed to take care of that. I have set this field to true before and it does not seem to have an effect. I'm sure they'll get around to fixing it eventually.

The efficiency of the animations also depends on how many animation nodes you have. You should only need 1 animation node to handle all of your animations for a particular component. Add an interpolator for each individual type of animation you want to occur (i.e. scaling, rotating, color-shifting, translating).